# I/O do solr aumenta com o passar do tempo

Tags: linux, algoritmo-de-busca, lucene, apache-solr

Estou rodando cerca de oito servidores com `solr` servers (versão `3.5`) atrás de um Load Balancer. Todos os servidores são idênticos e o LB está configurado com peso pelo número de conexões. Os servidores têm cerca de 4 milhões de documentos e recebem um fluxo constante de requisições. Não há praticamente escrita de novos documentos. Quando o solr inicia, funciona muito bem. Mas após algum tempo rodando, ele começa a levar mais tempo para responder e o nível de I/O fica maluco, chegando a subir a 100%. Veja o gráfico do  New Relic:

[image]

Se o servidor se comporta bem inicialmente, por que começa a falhar depois de um tempo? E se eu re-inicio o solr, o I/O volta a ser baixo por um tempo, aumentando novamente depois.

[Pergunta original em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110242/solr-i-o-increases-over-time)

Answer (score 2):

A resposta para essa pergunta está ligada com o conteúdo [desse post](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html).

O que acontece nesse caso é que as buscas desse sistema dependem de muita leitura dos índices do `solr`. Como os índices ficam em disco, o I/O é alto. Para otimizar um acesso frequente ao disco, o Linux faz cache das áreas de disco mais lidas em memória. Ele usa a memória não ocupada por aplicações para esse cache. Quando a memória fica cheia ele volta a ter que ler do disco. Por essa razão, quando o `solr` inicia, a JVM ocupa menos espaço em memória e por isso, o espaço que sobra é suficiente para o cache do índice.

(O problema ocorreu em um servidor com 15Gb de RAM e um índice `solr` com 20Gb)

A solução para o problema é simplesmente aumentar a quantidade de memória da máquina, para que todo o índice caiba nela. Dessa forma, não haverá praticamente I/O ao ler o índice.